# How to achieve motion blur effect in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

How to achieve "motion effect" in SceneKit? Motion effect is that blur that gets created if you shoot (with a camera) fast moving objects. I am running an action on a node and would like a little blur in the direction of moving when the node is moving, to emphasise that the node is moving fast. Can this be done in SceneKit?

This image has motion effect - blur applied to the whole scene. you can tell that the camera is moving inwards by the direction of blur lines. I only want to apply motion blur to a single object and not while scene.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In recent versions of SceneKit, motion blur is built in — you can just set the [`motionBlurIntensity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1644099-motionblurintensity) on your scene’s camera.

In iOS 10, motion blur is for camera motion only — moving objects won’t blur. (You have to set the `movabilityHint` for nodes that you want to *not* blur when the camera moves fast.)

In iOS 11 and later, moving objects can also blur, so you can just set `motionBlurIntensity` on the camera and everything “just works”.

The rest of this answer predates iOS 10, and is still relevant if you’re (for some reason) supporting iOS 9.x or older.

---

To get a really good motion blur effect you'd have to write your own shaders and maybe even replace some of the SceneKit CPU-side pipeline -- not for the faint of heart.

For an easier approximation that might still give you some bang for your buck, take a look at [the `node.filters` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNNode/filters) and Core Image filters. By selectively applying a linear or zoom blur filter to certain nodes, and carefully setting (or even animating) the filter parameters, you might get a convincing fake motion blur.

Comment: Be aware that going the route of using CIFilters instead of implementing a blur shader will have significant performance implications.  I’m talking potentially 200MB allocated for the filter.

Comment: True. Luckily you don’t need to worry about that much anymore, as SceneKit has had at least some level of motion blur built in since 2016... I just hadn’t updated the answer in a while. Now I have.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into writing a motion blur fragment shader, in either GLSL or Metal Shading Language.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 10 introduced `camera.motionBlurIntensity` for SCNCamera. Values are between 0.0 and 1.0, with the default at 0.0.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1644099-motionblurintensity